# Will or Be going to? I am in doubt in these sentences. Help!

Tags: future-tense, will-vs-going-to

Please, I would really appreciate if you can help me with these sentences using WILL or BE GOING TO....I do not know if they are correct. My try:

1-Mr Sinclair **won´t be** very happy with me. It is the third time I forgot my homework.

2-Do not worry. I moved the glass away from the edge of the table. It **is not going to fall** off.

3-Sorry. James and Tom a**re not going to play** football today because they are both ill.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to ELU.  One feature of this sight is that you can search for previous related questions.  If you search on ‘continuous future’ or ‘going to’ you will find quite a few.  In your examples, either ‘will’ or ‘..be going to’ will do.  There is a very slight difference of nuance, perhaps.  2. is saying something about the condition the glass is now in, compared with before I moved it.  It is more than a prediction. The speaker is saying the glass is not in danger of falling.

Answer (score 0):

You have them largely correct.

1. > Mr. Sinclair won't be very happy with me. **This** is the third time I **have forgotten** my homework.
2. > **Don't** worry, I moved the glass away from the edge of the table, **It's not** going to fall off.
3. > Sorry. James and Tom **can not** play football today, **as** they are ill.